# How to stop Visual Studio from grouping files

Tags: visual-studio

It automatically puts .ts files underneath .html files, how can I stop that?

I know I can unlink individual files by editing the project file. How can I prevent it from linking future files?

Comment: You ever figure this one out, trying to remove this behavior myself!

Comment: Nope. I stopped using VS for web stuff. It hates JS, Node, and NPM.